# How to slice a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I'm trying to use slice to delete first 3 characters of string inside json.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
  });
  setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON("IOCounter.html", function(data) {
      $('#testTime').text(htmlDecode(slice(3(data.testTime))));
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <p id="testTime"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

So I'm trying to write the content of testTime inside p id=testTime, but I need to write it without first 3 characters. When I try to use slice, like it's shown in the exapmle, it doesnt work. data.testTime is a string.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Is `data.testTime` is date object , timestamp or string?

Comment: Post the what is `data`

Comment: data is a string

Comment: Then just use data.substring(3, data.length), assuming data is 'id=testTime'

Comment: What is your post data? Like JSON object. Just post it into your question description.

Comment: _“When I try to use slice, like it's shown in the exapmle, it doesnt work.”_ - show us where you defined your function `slice` then. Or did you not define one? There is a big difference between calling a “stand-alone” function, and actually calling a defined method on some type of object.

Comment: Make sure you mark the correct answer, please.

Comment: @CBroe look at  $('#testTime').text(htmlDecode(slice(3(data.testTime)))); that was the example i've used, but its not working like this

Comment: I know what you used, you don’t need to repeat that. And that is in no way an answer to what I actually asked you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple.

Slice is a method, not a function.

It can be used on arrays and/or strings.

Array method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

String method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

What you are looking for is the String method, but they both work the same. The String method just treats the string like an array of characters.

```
data.testTime.slice(3)
```

Comment: you did nearly exactly what I was asking for. I wanted to remove the first 3 letters, not to keep them. Anyways thank you!

Comment: Yes, so in that case, it's `.slice(3)`

Comment: I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To remove first 3 character from string, you can simply do `'stringsample'.substring(3)` , it will return `'ingsample'`